# Where is app.run() called when using the Application Factory in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

In my application I'd like to add some parameters to the `app.run()` command.

Without modules, that would be easy:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(parameter=value)
```

However, I am using the [application factory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/) approach, which does not seem to have an explicit call to that function directly.

Is there any way I can still add parameters? I know that I can do it by passing the parameters in command line to the `flask run` command, but I'd prefer to avoid going that route.

Answer (score -1):

tell exactly what parameter you wanna add? some parameter like debug,host, port, ... can added with config dictionary:

```
app.config["SERVERNAME"] = "ip:port"
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
```